# Basic API wrapper around a Restful service - follow-up

Tags: c#, api, rest, wrapper

This is a follow up from my previous post: [Basic API wrapper around a Restful service](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/140412/basic-api-wrapper-around-a-restful-service)

I'm writing a basic wrapper around a restful service that returns a list of Stores. Naturally, I want to make it completely testable (that's a major requirement!).

I have split out my `TopmanClient` class so that just deals with the rest client bits (using RestSharp).

I then inject the `TopmanClient` class into my `TopmanRepository`:

```
public class TopmanClient : ITopmanClient
{
    private readonly IRestClient _restClient;
    private const string BaseUrl = "https://public.Topman.com/";
    private const string AcceptTenant = "uk";
    private const string AcceptLanguage = "en-GB";

    public TopmanClient()
    {
        _restClient = new RestClient(BaseUrl);

        _restClient.AddDefaultHeader("Accept-Tenant", AcceptTenant);
        _restClient.AddDefaultHeader("Accept-Language", AcceptLanguage);
    }

    public IRestRequest Request(string url)
    {
        return new RestRequest(url);
    }

    public IRestResponse<T> Execute<T>(IRestRequest request) where T : new()
    {
        return _restClient.Execute<T>(request);
    }
}

public class TopmanRepository : ITopmanRepository<Store>
{
    private readonly ITopmanClient _topmanClient;
    public TopmanRepository(ITopmanClient topmanClient)
    {
        _topmanClient = topmanClient;
    }

    public List<Store> Get(string query)
    {
        var request = _topmanClient.Request("stores");

        request.RootElement = "Stores";
        request.AddQueryParameter("q", query);

        var response = _topmanClient.Execute<List<Store>>(request);

        return response.Data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As @t3chb0t says, the implementation is clean enough already.

However, if you wanted to go one step further, I would inject the implementation of `IRestSharp` into the `TopmanClient`, so that you can then test the behaviour of your default implementation when an API error occurs. For instance, if the API returns a `404 Not Found`, how will your client behave? How about if a deserialisation error occurs?

For double bonus points, you could run the test once passing in a mock `IRestClient`; then run the same test again passing in a real `RestClient` - you now have a test of your client and an integration test for the API (although make sure you are pointing at a non-production API, or a test account, or a sandbox). Whether or not you include those in your automated builds or automated deployments, I'll leave up to you.

Answer (score 0):

All of these strings should be moved to a configuration file.

```
private const string BaseUrl = "https://public.Topman.com/";
private const string AcceptTenant = "uk";
private const string AcceptLanguage = "en-GB";
```

Hardcoding them into your lib is going to make it *very* difficult to run this against a test environment. Also, if any of these values would need to change, you'd have to recompile & redeploy this code. Life's much simpler when we can just modify some values in a config and move on with our lives.